# Odoo / OpenERP How to set Order Line field to readonly based on field from Customer?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I have a boolean field `x_no_change` in Customer. I need to access this field in Quotation and set `price_unit` for each sale.order.line on the Quotation to readonly if `x_no_change` is true. I cannot seem to be able to access or check `x_no_change` for each sale.order.line.

my_partner.py

```
class my_partner(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    _columns = {
        'x_no_change': fields.boolean(string='No change allowed')
    }
    _defaults = {
        'x_no_change': False
    }
```

my_quote.py

```
class my_quote(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'
    _columns = {
        'x_customer_no_change': fields.related('partner_id', 'x_no_change', type='boolean', string="No change allowed")
    }
    _defaults = {
        'x_customer_no_change': False
    }
    def onchange_partner_id(self, cr, uid, ids, partner, context=None):
        partner = self.pool.get('res.partner').browse(cr, uid, partner, context=context)
        #some other codes
        val['x_customer_no_change'] = partner.x_no_change or False
        return {'value': val}

class my_order_line(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'
    _columns = {
        'x_order_no_change': fields.related('sale.order', 'x_customer_no_change', type='boolean', string='No change allowed')
    }
```

my_quote.xml

```
<record id="view_sale_line_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="model">sale.order</field>
  <field name="name">sale.order.line.form.inherit</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <!-- x_customer_no_change on sale.order gets checked on change and appears to work perfectly -->
    <xpath expr="//group/field[@name='partner_shipping_id']" position="after">
      <field name="x_customer_no_change"/>
    </xpath>
    <!-- Not working: error -->
    <xpath expr="//tree/field[@name='price_unit']" position="attributes">
      <attribute name="attrs">{'readonly':[('x_order_no_change','=',True)]}</attribute>
    </xpath>
  </field>
</record>
```

> Uncaught Error: QWeb2 - template['ListView.row']: Runtime Error:
>   Error: Unknown field x_order_no_change in domain
>   [["x_order_no_change","=",true]]

What am I missing? How can I set the readonly attribute for each order line item depending on the `x_no_change` value set for the selected Customer? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Even if it would work, readonly fields and their values won't be saved if you hit the Save button in Odoo. So you have to do two things to implement your logic here. First ofcourse the readonly mechanism and second get the price on order write again (because the client won't send the value if readonly).

Comment: If this is the only use of the `x_customer_no_change` fields, it might be easier to set it as related field to `partner.x_no_change`.

Comment: @CZoellner I get what you mean... so loading the value of `x_no_change` on sale order form as `x_customer_no_change` will not result in sale.order.line being able to read this unless sale order is saved - is that right? In that case, how can I get sale.order.line to read from `parent.partner_id.x_no_change`? I tried using exactly that in XML but it complained about domain.

Comment: @dgeorgiev Tried but it did not work for me. Python complained about KeyError....

Comment: You are defining the field in `sale.order`, but I see you are using it in a `tree`, where it is probably another model (perhaps `sale.order.line`). If that is the case, you will need to define the field in this model, before you can use it.

Comment: @dgeorgiev Tried that too but the field defined in sale.order.line is not picking up `x_customer_no_change` on sale.order which was checked from related field `partner_id.x_no_change`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my_partner.py

```
class my_partner(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    x_no_change = fields.Boolean(string='No change allowed', store=True)
```

> my_quote.py

```
class my_order_line(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'

    def product_id_change(self, cr, uid, ids, pricelist, product, qty=0,
        uom=False, qty_uos=0, uos=False, name='', partner_id=False,
        lang=False, update_tax=True, date_order=False, packaging=False, fiscal_position=False, flag=False, context=None):

        res = super(my_order_line, self).product_id_change(cr, uid, ids, pricelist, product, qty,
            uom, qty_uos, uos, name, partner_id,
            lang, update_tax, date_order, packaging, fiscal_position, flag, context)

        partner_obj = self.pool.get('res.partner')
        partner = partner_obj.browse(cr, uid, partner_id)

        if not flag:
            res['value']['x_no_change_line'] = partner.x_no_change

        return res

    x_no_change_line = fields.Boolean(string='No change allowed', readonly=True)
```

> my_quote.xml

```
<record id="view_sale_line_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="model">sale.order</field>
  <field name="name">sale.order.line.form.inherit</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//tree/field[@name='price_unit']" position="after">
      <field name="x_no_change_line" invisible="1"/>
    </xpath>
    <xpath expr="//tree/field[@name='price_unit']" position="attributes">
      <attribute name="attrs">{'readonly':[('x_no_change_line','=',True)]}</attribute>
    </xpath>
  </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Hello jeszy, How can this function use for Odoo10

Comment: I have a button on above sales order line. And when click on that button than wizard open, in this wizard we add product pack and quantity. and after ok button these values(product pack, qty, price) return in sales order line(product_id, qty, unit_price). So, i want that when check_box condition is True then not editable permission allow in sales order line. else user can change quantity for product in other row?

Answer (score 0):

> my_partner.py

```
class my_partner(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    _columns = {
               'x_no_change' : fields.boolean(string='No change allowed'),
}
```

> my_quote.py

```
class my_quote(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    _columns = {
                   'x_customer_no_change' : fields.related('partner_id', 'x_no_change', type='boolean', string='No change allowed'),
    }
```

> my_quote.xml

```
<record id="view_sale_line_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="model">sale.order</field>
  <field name="name">sale.order.line.form.inherit</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">

    <!-- x_customer_no_change on sale.order gets checked on change and appears to work perfectly -->
    <xpath expr="//group/field[@name='partner_shipping_id']" position="after">
      <field name="x_customer_no_change"/>
    </xpath>

    <xpath expr="//tree/field[@name='price_unit']" position="attributes">
      <attribute name="attrs">{'readonly':[('x_customer_no_change','=',True)]}</attribute>
    </xpath>
  </field>
</record>
```

Comment: `KeyError: 'x_customer_no_change'`. I thought maybe it's typo and it should have been `x_no_change` - same error. Declared field with `'x_customer_no_change' = fields.boolean(related='partner_id.x_no_change')` but bumped into the same error.

Comment: The error appears because the domain used for readonly is on model `sale.order.line`. Maybe it is enough two define the field again as related field on that model.

Comment: @CZoellner Updated codes above to include attempt for the related field on sale.order `x_customer_no_change` but greeted with exception.

Comment: It's really hard to follow the code ;-) It should be `'x_customer_no_change': fields.related('order_id', 'x_customer_no_change', type='boolean', string='No change allowed')` in combination with Vishnu's answer.

Comment: you are correct jessy it should be 'x_customer_no_change' : fields.related('partner_id', 'x_no_change', type='boolean', string='No change allowed'),

Comment: @VishnuLoyal Not working. Unable to find field error :(